# Multiclient chat app not working properly

Tags: c#, user-interface, networking

I'm currently working on a P2P chat app that uses multicasting to transfer data between users on the same LAN(I'm using class D IP addresses for this). Here some of the code I've written so far.

**NetworkManager.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    /*
     *This class encapsulates the sending and receiving of the data using a Udp client
     */
    public class NetworkManager
    {
        private UdpClient client;
        private readonly string groupAddress = "230.0.0.1";
        private readonly int port = 8899;
        private byte[] data;
        private IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("230.0.0.1"), 8899);
        private UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        private bool joined //checks whether a client has joined a group or not;

        public NetworkManager()
        {
            client = new UdpClient(port);
            client.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(groupAddress));
            joined = true;
        }
        public void Send(string msg)
        {
            byte[] bdata = encoding.GetBytes(msg);
            client.SendAsync(bdata, bdata.Length, remoteEP);
        }

        public string Receive()
        {
            IPEndPoint ep = null;
            data = client.Receive(ref ep);
            string msg = encoding.GetString(data);
            return msg;
        }

        public void Leave()
        {
            if (joined)
            {
                client.DropMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(groupAddress));
                joined = false;
            }

        }

        public void Join()
        {
            if (!joined)
            {
                client.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(groupAddress));
                joined = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private NetworkManager ns;
        private string msg;
        private bool done;
        private string name;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //tboxName is where the user enters his/her name
            name = tboxName.Text;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Enter a valid name", "Chat Form", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }

            if (ns == null)
            {
                ns = new NetworkManager();
            }
            else
            {
                ns.Join();
            }

            btnSend.Enabled = true;
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            btnStop.Enabled = true;

            Task.Run(() => Listen());
            string s = String.Format("{0} has joined the chat.", name);
            ns.Send(s);


        }

        private void DisplayMessage()
        {
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("t");
            //tboxMsg is where the chat messages are displayed
            tboxMsg.Text += time + " " + msg + "\r\n";
        }

        private void Listen()
        {
            done = false;
            try
            {

                while (!done)
                {
                    msg = ns.Receive();
                    BeginInvoke(new Action(DisplayMessage));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, ex.ToString(), "Exception Occured", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tboxSend.Text)) return;
            string text = String.Format("{0}: {1}", name, tboxSend.Text);
            string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("t");
            tboxMsg.Text += time + " " + text + "\r\n";
            ns.Send(text);         
            tboxSend.Clear();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s = String.Format("{0} has left the chat.", name);
            ns.Send(s);
            ns.Leave();
            btnSend.Enabled = false;
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;

        }


    }
}
```

When I run the app from two different direcotries on the same host with different values for the ports, it works properly as shown in the picture below:
[image]
However, when I run it from two different hosts on the same LAN, it doesn't seem to work properly. It doesn't receive or send any message to the remote host. I can only see on the text box what I'm writing and the same for the user on the other end. I have turned off both firewalls on the host just it case that is the cause, but still it doesn't work. Here is the program running this case:
    [image]
What am I doing wrong here? Why isn't working in this situation?

Thanks in advance.